# SourceMember records behavior and lifespan

Tags: salesforcedx, source

With source-tracking activated scratch and dev orgs you will find the SourceMember sObject on Tooling api.

I have observed that whenever a change is made in the org, a record is created in its table, allowing me to sync my local sfdx project.

However, a few hours later, the SourceMember table was empty !
I was the only user accessing this org.

How, why and when a SourceMember record can be automatically deleted ?

Comment: did you do anything during those few hours (ex. sfdx commands, etc).

Comment: yes actually I reset the password. I’ll be updating the comment section with any arising similar things, and everyone is welcome to do so until we have a full library :)